# How does database connection pooling work with Celery (& Django) for prefork & gevent connection types?

Tags: django, postgresql, celery, connection-pooling

I have a django server, alongside a celery background worker, both  of them interact with a Postgres database.

I have a single celery worker running gevent with 500 concurrency flag. This gives 500 threads under a single worker to run and execute  tasks. My question is do all of these threads try to use the same database connection? Or will it try to create 500 connections.

In a prefork pool, does it create a connection per process?

I saw in django documentation (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/databases/#connection-management), it says that it allows persistent connections, so connections are reused, but I'm not sure how this translates to celery?